# Is it possible to assign a Pattern to a Contact?

Tags: experience-profile

In Sitecore 9, am I able to assign a Pattern to a Contact?

I think the answer is no.  The system uses Patterns Cards to identify matches to Contacts.  Additionally, from the Experience Profile, I do not see a way to manually assign a Pattern Card to a specific Contact.

While viewing a specific Contact in the Experience Profile dashboard, I was trying to find a way to assign a Pattern to a specific Contact.  My intent is to override a Pattern that the system has assigned to a Contact.

Comment: You have to login in as the user in code and execute/score the proper profiles cause the pattern card to be assigned. But you can't just write the pattern card to the contact directly. 9.0 or 9.1?

Comment: The specific use case is for a Sitecore 9.0 installation.  However, I would be interested in an answer for 7.2, 8.2 and 9.1 as well.

Comment: 7.2 did not have pattern cards. 8.2 can only be done in session, so you code would have to log in as the user and score them. In 9.x you can call xConnect directly and do it. Let me think about the code.

Comment: Do do it in 8.2, this is the code. You get a profile card, add a values to it, score it and update the pattern card. But you will have to log into the website as them and do this in the Sitecore session. https://github.com/buildabonfire/Bonfire-Company-Personalization/blob/master/src/Feature/Kickfire/Analytics/Pipelines/createVisit/AdvancedIpData.cs#L116

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mainly no, not offline.

Pattern cards are only assigned by scoring profiles in a real web session. So if you want to write code to log every single user in via a web request. Assign profile values that will trigger a certain pattern card and then score the profile, yes.

But directly adding pattern cards to contacts, no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is your question, but if you are searching for a way to classify the contacts you can look at the personas here https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-profile-key-or-persona.html

Comment: While viewing a specific Contact in the Experience Profile dashboard, I was trying to find a way to assign a Pattern to a specific Contact. My intent is to manually override a Pattern that the system has assigned to a Contact.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that experience profile is read only at the moment, But you can develop a small extension to sitecore to update the contact facets in xconnect, that can be easily done.